# systemctl hibernate - crash on execution

Tags: linux, fedora, suspend

`systemctl hibernate` or anything similar (i.e. suspend and hybrid-sleep) crashes the PC on invocation. 
When called, it first correctly executes all scripts in `system-sleep` and then logs out any non-root user, after which the screen turns blank and he PC crashes. 
The power button is still glowing, but in such a state the PC cannot be recovered; every time this happens I have to forcibly turn it off by holding the power button for 6 seconds. The PC starts completely normally after that and upon login in the notification manager tells me `systemctl hibernate completed succesfully`.
A call of `free -m` tells me that the swap-file is completely empty.

I am not sure whether this problem occurs due to an incorrect swapfile or if systemctl crashes before it can even attempt to suspend the PC's memory to swap. Considering the notifications tell me that systemctl succeeded executing I think it's probably the former, I am unsure why it would crash *before* the PC turns off, though.

I've set up my swap-file manually using [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/) tutorial and rebooted multiple times afterwards. I'd tried using a swap partition before which lead to the same result.

This is what my fstab file looks like:

```
/dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-root /     ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=947C-7EF0          /boot/efi                          vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-home /home ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-var  /var  ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/sda5 /mnt/sda5 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0
```

This is part of the output `lsblk -f` gives:

```
└─sda8  LVM2_member            r3BdLl-j14c-2V1r-BNVL-bMP8-3sCZ-AeT2Ae 
  ├─fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-swap
  │     swap                   aee59aff-f827-4038-83b7-3d19f2249257
```

`dmesg | grep swap`

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.1.10-200.fc22.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora_auditorium-hg-dock-1-156/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_auditorium-hg-dock-1-156/root rhgb quiet resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-swap
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.1.10-200.fc22.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora_auditorium-hg-dock-1-156/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora_auditorium-hg-dock-1-156/root rhgb quiet resume=/dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-swap
[    0.506987] PM: Checking hibernation image partition /dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-swap
[    4.074893] Adding 10485756k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-1 extents:12 across:12886012k SSFS
```

`dmesg | grep hiber`

```
[    0.506987] PM: Checking hibernation image partition /dev/mapper/fedora_auditorium--hg--dock--1--156-swap
[    1.553385] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dhibernate\x2dresume.slice.
[    1.553390] systemd[1]: Starting system-systemd\x2dhibernate\x2dresume.slice.
[    3.078912] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
```

Some outputs of `dmesg | grep -i acpi`. I haven't listed them all; I got some which I deemed might help answering the question:

```
[    0.141326] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S1_] (20150410/hwxface-580)
[    0.141335] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20150410/hwxface-580)
[    0.141342] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S3_] (20150410/hwxface-580)
[    0.141355] ACPI: (supports S0 S4 S5)
[    0.141356] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.141392] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.142937] ACPI: Power Resource [PG00] (on)
[    0.143284] ACPI: Power Resource [PG01] (on)
[    0.143598] ACPI: Power Resource [PG02] (on)
[    0.155912] ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
[    0.155983] ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
[    0.156043] ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
[    0.156101] ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
[    0.156158] ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
[    0.156935] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-3e])
[    0.156940] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    0.157378] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability]
[    0.157379] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    0.158209] pci 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.158514] pci 0000:00:1c.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.158663] pci 0000:00:1c.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.159500] pci 0000:01:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.161586] pci 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
```

[...and so on, until...]

```
[    0.158209] pci 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.158514] pci 0000:00:1c.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.158663] pci 0000:00:1c.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.159500] pci 0000:01:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.161586] pci 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
```

And lastly, here is a block that a merely copied because it said "warning". No idea whether that even has something to do with hibernation.

```
[    3.950838] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.IETM._ART: Return Package type mismatch at index 0 - found Integer, expected Reference (20150410/nspredef-297)
[    3.950844] ACPI: Invalid package element [0]: got number, expecting [R]
[    4.116950] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x000000000000F040-0x000000000000F05F conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000F040-0x000000000000F04F (\_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI) (20150410/utaddress-254)
```

Using `dmesg` I honestly have no idea what I'm looking for but maybe - or rather, most likely - it is helpful to someone more experienced seeing this post.

Comment: Did you check the output of `dmesg` for hibernate related messages?

Comment: @feverDream Good thing you mentioned that. I did not. I edited in some outputs but I'm too inexperienced to make sense of them, really. The first and third block seem interesting though.

Comment: There are quite few things that might be causing this (graphics drivers, kernel etc..)
Does suspend/hibernate work form the console? Try running `systemctl hibernate/suspend` from the console and see if it works. It might be one way to isolate the problem.

Comment: Also try running `journalctl` as a root user and see if anything shows up in there.